# Chartsjs exportar PNG automaticamente

Tags: php, javascript, chartjs

Eu preciso exportar um gráfico co Chartjs (versão 2.7) para PNG que consegui em:

https://jsfiddle.net/uabczmxa/

O único problema que preciso apertar o botão.

Alguém saberia o que modificar no javascript?

No final eu vou gerar um relatório com FPDF em PHP, por isso eu preciso do PNG.

Comment: O que é que pretende concretamente? Fazer download ao entrar na página? Qual é a dificuldade que tem?

Comment: Eu não conheço quase nada de javascript. Eu queria que ao exibir a página automaticamente salvasse a imagem sem precisar de um botão. Com a imagem salva eu vou gerar um relatório em PDF com o FPDF em PHP que manjo bem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas chame a função: `downloadImage();`, assim quando a página carregar ele executa a função sem a necessidade do click.

Coloquei a função no seu JSFiddle, e mandei executar novamente o código e fez o download da imagem sem a necessidade do click.

```
var chart_variable = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'My First Dataset',
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      title: {
         display: true,
         text: 'Chart Title'
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               stepSize: 1
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});

function downloadImage() {
   /* set new title */
   chart_variable.options.title.text = 'New Chart Title';
   chart_variable.update({
      duration: 0
   });
   // or, use
   // chart_variable.update(0);

   /* save as image */
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   link.href = chart_variable.toBase64Image();
   link.download = 'myImage.png';
   link.click();

   /* rollback to old title */
   chart_variable.options.title.text = 'Chart Title';
   chart_variable.update({
      duration: 0
   });
   // or, use
   // chart_variable.update(0);
}

//executa a função ao abrir a página.
downloadImage();
```

Comment: Também poderá colocar a função  na tag body com o event listener onload, ou seja `<body onload="downloadImage()">`. A diferença neste caso é que a função apenas ser executada quando a página tiver completamente carregada.

Comment: Deu certo, mas ainda não ficou bom, pois aparece baixando o arquivo, no fundo eu quero exportar a imagem para uma pasta e depois usar no meu relatório.